# exclude content from link preview

Tags: html

I always wonder how [pages like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkirk_(2017_film)) works on link preview structure. specifically "Infobox Section"? ([here](https://richpreview.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDunkirk_%282017_film%29&reload=true)) this section appears top of the content but always excluded from link previews.
How can we exclude one HTML section from link preview?

Answer (score 0):

You can't exclude any content from being visible to another website; your DOM is always publicly visible. [Rich Preview](https://richpreview.com/) just shows the **[`<meta>`](http://www.wordstream.com/meta-tags)** information for a website for use on sites like Google and Facebook. If you don't want information to show on Rich Preview, simply don't include the relevant information in your `<meta>` tags.

Comment: That is the point. link preview mainly works with meta name property. Question is, how Infobox section from article i mentioned, is excluded from description meta tag? // Infobox is created right inside of content area